# how to get Tor browser working again with the new 6.5 A1-Hardened update? Please help

Tags: help, update

On 6/7/16 Tor upgrade to 6.5 A1-hardened and I can't figure how to get the Tor browser working again? If anyone can help me out with this it would help me and a lot of other people out. Thank you, and I hope to hear from somebody soon.

Comment: we could use some more details on what you did, what you expected to happen and what did actually happen.